# how to set specific media for my background

Tags: html, css

after setting my background image to 100vw and height to 100vh how can i set a specific media for the width so when i decrease the page size i do not need to scroll left or right

```
body{
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.main{
  width: 100vw;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)50%), url(pexels-hasan-albari-1229861.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh; 
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no repeat;
}
```

This is what I tried.

Comment: you have to play with your background-size (you have it 2 times in .main by the way). Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

by default chrome for example have `margin: 8px`...